# VSTS Agent Issue

Tags: azure-pipelines

Trying to setup an agent configure an VSTS Agent and see the below error.

Enter User account to use for the service (press enter for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) >
The service already exists: vstsagent.xxx.dd-PC-085, it will be replaced
Could not delete service 'vstsagent.xx.dd-PC-085'

Because of the above am not able to deploy to IIS. Any input(s) and is there more information that I have to provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mainly because **an older agent you configured as service `vstsagent.xx.dd-PC-085` was running** (for build or release).

Please check the older agent status is idle and then configure your current agent again:

`.\config.cmd remove`, input your PAT to remove it.

`.\config.cmd` configure by steps and then config this agent as services again.

Comment: What is the PAT?

Comment: A PAT is your Personal Access Token. You have to generate this in ADO and assign proper scope for the PAT to assign auth access to resources as needed. See here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/howto-provision-deployment-group-agents?view=azure-devops#install-the-azure-pipelines-agent-azure-vm-extension @Meca